# Determining if I need a 32 bit or 64 bit driver for OSX 10.7.2

Tags: drivers, 64-bit, python, serial-port, 32-vs-64-bit

I'm looking to download an ftdi driver for OSX 10.7.2.
I will be using it for work I'm doing in python 2.7.x, using pySerial.

I have no idea how to determine whether I need to download the 32 or 64-bit version.  Can anyone advise how to work this out ?

Comment: Generally, 32 bit is more compatible, especially if you're developing for potentially 32 bit clients.

Comment: I need to know how to check which one I should use for my system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Terminal.app, entering the command "uname -a" will indicate if your system is running a 32 or 64-bit kernel. A 32-bit kernel will return RELEASE_I386 i386, while a 64-bit kernel will return RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64. Your software selection should match your kernel version. Source, [OSXDaily](http://osxdaily.com/2009/09/07/how-to-tell-if-youre-running-the-32-bit-or-64-bit-kernel-in-mac-os-x-snow-leopard/).

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Does this mean that I cannot run Python in 32-bit mode, or that all of the libraries that Python accesses need to be 64-bit?  That's the one thing I'm not clear about... for ex., I know of a couple applications that allow you to set which mode they run in within their inspector (theapp.app).